# Replace and remove text in Vue JS array of objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an array of objects which I pull in via an Axios request called 'uniquecolors'.
It looks like this:

```
     mycolors 
      color: [GREEN, RED, BLUE, YELLOW, ORANGE,ORANGE,GREEN,]
      color: [GREEN, RED, BLUE, YELLOW, ORANGE,ORANGE,GREEN,]
      color: [GREEN, RED, BLUE ]
      color: [YELLOW, ORANGE]
      color: [GREEN, GREEN,GREEN,RED]
      color: [ORANGE,GREEN,ORANGE,GREEN,RED]`
```

1. I would like to remove all colors apart from 'RED' and 'GREEN' for each object
2. I would like to replace 'RED' with 'Crimson'
3. I would like to replace 'GREEN' with 'Sage'

   ```
   `methods:
   ....

       const uniquecolorscationwithduplicates = uniquecolors
        .toString()
        .replace("RED", "Crimson")
        .replace("GREEN", "Sage")  
        .replace("YELLOW,", "")
        .split("|");``
   ```

This actually keeps all the colors but adds on Crimson and Sage. So it displays 'GREEN,Sage,RED,Crimson,BLUE, YELLOW, ORANGE' instead of replacing.

Why would that be?

To remove I have been replacing with a blank string. I know this is a bad way to code it but Im not sure how else to do this.

Ideally I'd like to change all instances of the colors when the page renders so any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, please describe axios response as json or something, response you described is ambigous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply achieve this by using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and [`String.replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) methods of JavaScript.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const arr = [{
  color: ['GREEN', 'RED', 'BLUE', 'YELLOW', 'ORANGE', 'ORANGE', 'GREEN']
},{
  color: ['GREEN', 'RED', 'BLUE', 'YELLOW', 'ORANGE', 'ORANGE', 'GREEN']
},{
  color: ['GREEN', 'RED', 'BLUE']
},{
  color: ['YELLOW', 'ORANGE']
},{
  color: ['GREEN', 'GREEN', 'GREEN', 'RED']
},{
  color: ['ORANGE', 'GREEN', 'ORANGE', 'GREEN', 'RED']
}];

const res = arr.map(({ color }) => {
  const filteredColor = color.filter(c => c === 'GREEN' || c === 'RED');
  const obj = {
    color: filteredColor.join().replaceAll('RED', 'Crimson').replaceAll('GREEN', 'Sage').split(',')
  };
  return obj;
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code, u can use map and filter.

```js
const mycolors = [
    {color: ['GREEN', 'RED', 'BLUE', 'YELLOW', 'ORANGE', 'ORANGE', 'GREEN']},
    {color: ['GREEN', 'RED', 'BLUE', 'YELLOW', 'ORANGE', 'ORANGE', 'GREEN']},
    {color: ['GREEN', 'RED', 'BLUE']},
    {color: ['YELLOW', 'ORANGE']},
    {color: ['GREEN', 'GREEN', 'GREEN', 'RED']},
    {color: ['ORANGE', 'GREEN', 'ORANGE', 'GREEN', 'RED']}
];

const colored = mycolors.map(({color}) => {
    let filtered = color.filter(col => col === 'RED' || col === 'GREEN')
        .map(el => {
            return el === 'RED' ? 'Crimson' : 'Sage';
        });
    return {color: filtered};
});

console.log(colored)
```